# When hovering over a div, how to add a class to another div?

Tags: javascript, css, hover

So I have a table including 2 divs. Each div contains an image and some text. I want that when hovering one of the div, the elements (all of them) of the other one get blurred.

// HTML

```
             <table>
                <tbody>
                    <div id="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="3"><img src="url"/></td>
                            <td><h2>Lorem ipsum</h2></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p><span class="important">Clients:</span> Lorem / Ipsum</p></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p><span class="important">Scope:</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p></td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>    
                        <tr class="separator">
                            <td colspan="2"></td>
                        </tr>
                    <div id="2">    
                        <tr>
                            <td rowspan="2"><img src="url"/></td>
                            <td><h2>Lorem</h2></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p><span class="important">Scope:</span> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p></td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>
                </tbody> 
            </table>
```

I created the class .blur to affect to the wanted div through js, but somehow, it doesn't work and neither text nor image are blurred.

// CSS

```
.blur {
color: transparent;
text-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 -webkit-filter: blur(10px);}
```

// JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#1').hover(function() {
    $('#2').addClass('.blur');
}, function() {
    $('#2').removeClass('.blur');
});

$('#2').hover(function() {
    $('#1').addClass('.blur');
}, function() {
    $('#1').removeClass('.blur');
});});
```

Here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/52v9y/

Where am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52v9y/1/).

You do not need a `.` when specifying classes in `addClass` and `removeClass` functions since the only argument they accept are class attributes. Your html was also invalid since only `tr` elements can be a direct child of a `tbody`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid HTML code. You can't put your `div`s in the middle of the `table` code. That's why it doesn't work.

Also you didn't have jQuery included. I've updated the fiddle, you can take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/52v9y/2/

Comment: nice, thanks, that's indeed a better way to use 2 differents tables instead of one !

Answer (score 0):

Discard the `div` elements to have valid html. The class names in your selectors come without he Leasing dot, as other contributors have advised. Assign the classes to the `tr` elements instead. Depending on your actual use Case, consider adjusting the class selectors in your Event Handlers (eg. `$("#1 td.whatever")`)